# Return Iterable With Mock Python

Tags: python, mocking

I'm trying to use Mock, to simulate a function in python. Here is my code:

```
    resp, content = request(...)
```

The request() function needs to return two values. Here's what I tried:

```
    with patch("syncdatetime.py") as sync_mock:
        sync_mock.request.return_value = [obj, '']
```

But when I run the test, I get the error "Mock object is not iterable." The request function returns an object of type Mock instead of a list. How can I patch the request function so that it returns a list?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Note of disclosure, I'm new to mock so I'm not an expert, however, I have just suffered the same problem and found that setting the `side_effect` attribute to a function that returns an array fixes things

From your example code, change:

```
with patch("syncdatetime.py") as sync_mock:
    sync_mock.request.return_value = [obj, '']
```

to

```
with patch("syncdatetime.py") as sync_mock:
    sync_mock.request.side_effect = function_returning_list
```

and define

```
def function_returning_list(arg_list_of_choice):
    #anything you want to do goes here
    #then
    return your_list
```

Comment: I haven't tried this but I did find a simpler solution. Instead of patching the module, patch the function itself and then set patch.return_value. Honestly, I'm not entirely sure why this works but this way, the function isn't returning a Mock object. Thanks for the response, though.

Answer (score 20):

I suspect that your problem is that you are not using the instance of mock that you think you are.  By default an instance of Mock returns a Mock when called.

```
>>> m = mock.Mock()
>>> type(m())
<class 'mock.mock.Mock'>
```

It looks like your call to `request` is returning a Mock because the `return_value` has not been initialized which means that `resp, content = request()` is trying to unpack a Mock object.

```
>>> m = mock.Mock()
>>> (a, b) = m()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'Mock' object is not iterable
```

You shouldn't need to use `side_effect` to return a list.  Assigning `return_value` should work.

```
>>> m = mock.Mock()
>>> m.return_value = ['a', 'b']
>>> (a, b) = m()
>>> a
'a'
>>> b
'b'
```